# Routing Sysout values to JTextArea

Tags: java, awt, jtextarea

So, I've a method in file 'Functions.java' as below.

```
public static void updateDataToExcel (String ExcelFileName) throws IOException {
...
...
System.out.println("File Not Found!");
...
Sysout("File Created!");
...
Sysout("Data Updated");
...
}
```

Now, I'm calling this in my main  class where I've a 'Text Area'. So, whenever a 'sysout' is reached, I want the data to be updated in below text Area and no in console.

```
JTextArea txtrExecutionStatus = new JTextArea();
txtrExecutionStatus.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
txtrExecutionStatus.setText("Execution Status:\r\n");
txtrExecutionStatus.setBounds(53, 188, 378, 102);
panel.add(txtrExecutionStatus);
```

For this, I tried access "txtrExecutionStatus" by creating class to my main class (Object.java) but the JTextArea is not accessible.

Any suggestions? I remmeber reading long time back that we can route the sysout from Console to other objects but couldn't recollect / get answer from google.

Thank you in advance!! And, Happy new year too, in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.out may be redirected with `System.setOut(PrintStream)`.
A PrintStream operates on bytes, OutputStream.
So one has to make an OutputStream, that does the conversion of those bytes to String (Unicode). Then `JTextArea.append` can be used.
I set the autoflushing of the PrintStream to true. And overrode flush to flush line wise. For a bit better performance.

```
JTextArea txtrExecutionStatus = new JTextArea();
...
OutputStream textAreaOut = new OutputStream() {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream lineBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        lineBuffer.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        byte[] bytes = lineBuffer.toByteArray();
        lineBuffer.reset();
        String line = new String(bytes); // Default OS encoding.
        txtrExecutionStatus.append(line);
    }
}

PrintStream redirect = new PrintStream(textAreaOut, true);
System.setOut(redirect);
```

Comment: Joop, there are couple of issues. When I print sysout("1st line"); and then sysout("2nd line"), I get two outputs in text area as below.Output #1:

1st sys out1st sys out
1st sys out

Output #2:

1st sys out1st sys out
1st sys out
1st sys out
2nd Sys out1st sys out
2nd Sys out
1st sys out
2nd Sys out

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `lineBuffer.reset(), reemptying the buffer of the outputted bytes, and added that code a bit later. You evidently already used the original version.